# How to get current date as per logged in user in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I tried to get current date using `new Date()` but it is returning date as in users laptop. Also tried `$A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat"))`. How to get date based on users timezone?

[Time Zone of logged in user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVQDs.png)

Here expected date is 5th June but it's returning date from my local system.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $Locale global value provider returns information about the current user’s preferred locale. You can try using $locale.timezone in Aura to get the time zone and perhaps use it along with new Date to get the Date similar to the current loggged in user's timezone.

> **Updated Snippet:**

```
var timezone = $A.get("$Locale.timezone");
console.log('Time Zone Preference in Salesforce ORG :'+timezone);
var mydate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: timezone})
console.log('Date Instance with Salesforce Locale timezone : '+mydate);

var localDate = new Date();
console.log('Local Date in Your Laptop : '+localDate);
var timezone = localDate.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(timezone);
```

> **Updated Output:**

[image: updated Date]

The offset -330 translates to UTC + 5:30 which is Asia/Kolkatta, if both your ORG and local Date is same, then it can mean only thing the timezone preference in your SALESFORCE ORG is Asia/Kolkatta. Kindly check your configurations.

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_locale_value_provider.htm

**Note :**

- Though **new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})** has native support in almost all the modern day browsers.
- It is recommended to use a library such as Timezone.js or moment.js etc for wider browser support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59215/discussion-between-venky-and-sumuga).